# Wrong decimal formula: I can't get the right value

Tags: formula, formula-field, null, decimal

I use this formula field in my apex code. But I have big troubles with it, because there should be different logic for values `0` and `NULL`.

[image]
If I choose `Treat blank fields as blanks`, I'll get `NULL` even if one of the Integer filds (`First__c` or `Second__c`) is `NOT NULL`. If I choose `Treat blank fields as zeroes`, my formula field will be `0` too. And this formula is incorrect, because in both variants I get `NULL`. And I don't know why.

```
IF(First__c != NULL && Second__c != NULL, First__c + Second__c ,
IF(First__c = NULL && Second__c  != NULL, Second__c ,
IF(First__c != NULL && Second__c = NULL, First__c , NULL)))
```

And if one of fields in `NULL` and another one is `0`, I want to get `0` in my formula field.

I don't want to change the formula type, because I have a lot of logic with it already. Can I do something with this?

Comment: did you try to use IsBlank function?

Comment: The ISBLANK function is the official way to test "!= NULL" in a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working formula.
this works in both the cases: **Treat blank fields as zeroes** and
**Treat blank fields as blanks**

```
IF(
    !ISBLANK(First__c) && !ISBLANK(Second__c),
    First__c + Second__c,
    IF(
        !ISBLANK(First__c), First__c,
        IF(!ISBLANK(Second__c), Second__c, 0)
    )
)
```

> If any of the values is null formula returns the nonnull value.
>
> If both of the values are null your formula will result in 0. If you want it to be null in this case replace 
>   `0` in formula with `null`

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing in my org with fields called Number1__c and Number2__c.

Set the field to `Treat blank fields as blank fields`

use the formula:

```
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Number1__c)), NOT(ISBLANK(gnsf__Number2__c))), gnsf__Number1__c + Number2__c,
IF(AND(ISBLANK(Number1__c), NOT(ISBLANK(Number2__c))), Number2__c,
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Number1__c)), ISBLANK(Number2__c)), Number2__c, NULL)))
```

### More Info:

At first I thought that your formula would work which is why I had to try for myself. I also did some simpler version to determine what SFs default behavior was.

I tried `IF(Number2__c = null, 0, Number2__c)` just to see what would happen. Even if the value was null, the second parameter was always returned (0 was never displayed unless Number2__c was set to 0).

Then I tried `IF(ISNULL(Number2__c), 0, Number2__c)` this worked. This means that SFDC knows the value is null, but doesn't support `number = null`.

`IsBlank` is more powerful than `IsNull` as it doesn't just look for a null value. It also supports strings which `IsNull` does not. Because of this it is best practice to use `IsBlank`

I've gotten into the habit of using the built in functions in formulas as opposed to the programmer syntax. For instance use `AND(BoolExpr1, Boolexpr2)` instead of `&&` and `NOT(BoolExpr)` instead of `!` as well as the above `ISBLANK()` instead of `= null` as these seem to be much more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your help